# Web application database load reduction

Tags: database, caching, jakarta-ee

I am using a combination of JSF,Servlets and Beans for a web application.The thing is I hit the database for some data and this data is populated on the user page in a chart manner using JFree chart.But the problem is,I dont want to hit the database each time,one query is enough to get all the data.So I want a logic which hits the database only once and gathers the data perhaps in a bean and then populates it according to the user request.Can this be done in my same application,should I be using Java Script to do this.I have the logic to populate the data but I dont have any idea where to put the Data Access Object method so that it executes only once.

Comment: Your data access method probably only loads the data from the database and returns it. You could hit the database when the session starts and keep it in the session scope. For that purpose you can use a session scoped managed bean. That way it will last for the session.

Comment: +1 for the idea,I managed to do it.

Comment: Depends on how you're handling persistence. Plain JDBC? JPA? Ol' Hibernate? Etc. The solution needs to be sought in exactly this corner. JPA for example offers 2nd level caching support out the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring cache-abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), and cache the data using EHcache

Comment: Its good,but I dont want to add more complexity to it.Is there any lightweight way to do this in JSF itself.

Comment: Cache the result of method manually in your created datastructure before calling method check it. in other word create caching mechanism by hand but I would say better to reuse